# Custom expandable list Android

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, expandablelistview

I need to create a custom expandable list. When the list is expanded, it should display the items arranged in rows and columns like a matrix with a radiobutton below each item for selection.

How is this done?

[EDIT] I don't have a picture. Here is a very similar thing. http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html But instead of the list entries-Vechicle no.1, Vechicle no.2 which are placed horizontally, I need the entries to be placed in the form of a grid with each item having a radiobutton under it.

Comment: IMHO, it starts by you uploading an image that better explains what you are looking for.

Comment: I have added a similar picture. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a GridView.  It's a 2 dimension list view, where each item in the grid can have whatever layout you wish (defined in another xml file, usually).

Comment: Do you have any link for an example?